# How to write <c:if> - jstl tag - comparing map key with struts formbean element

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl

I need to retrieve list values from a map of type `Map<String,List<HashMap<String, Object>>>` in JSP based on a condition. The condition is to compare map key with formbean variable. Rightnow, I am doing multi level iterations. Firstly, I am iterating the map to retrieve key and an inner iterate loop to retrieve list values.

So far, I have like this

```html
<c:forEach items="${addRatingExceptionForm.ratingsMap}" var="entry"> 
  <c:set var="key" value="${entry.key}"/>
  <jsp:useBean id="key" type="java.lang.String" />
  <c:if test= '<%= key.equalsIgnoreCase(addRatingExceptionForm.getRatingElementDropdown()) %> ' >
    <c:forEach items="${entry.value}" var="item"> 
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="addRatingException_timeline_earlyAsn" value="${item.RatingInstanceValue}"  class="ajaxContentTrigger  method_Load_exceptionType ajaxLoadingTrigger|addRatingException_exceptionType clearErrors"/>  
        <label for="addRatingException_timeline_earlyAsn">${item.RatingInstanceValue}</p></label>   
      </li>
    </c:forEach>
  </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

But it errors on the `<c:if>` tag.

Comment: The functional requirement is not understood. Please elaborate the functional requirement in detail and/or post *real* pseudocode instead of failed code attempts as those are not helpful in understanding what you *actually* want.

Comment: `<%=${entry.key}.equalsIgnoreCase(addRatingExceptionForm.getRatingElementDropdown()) %>` - just as a sidenote: the scriptlet part between `<%=` and `%>` is executed *before* the expressions like `${entry.key}` are evaluated and thus that code can't work.

Comment: I need to retrieve list values from a map of type Map<String,List<HashMap<String, Object>>> in jsp based on a condition. The condition is to compare map key with formbean variable. Rightnow, I am doing multi level iterations. Firstly, I am iterating the map to retrieve key and an inner iterate loop to retrieve list values.

Comment: That's more clear. In the future, please put that as such straight in the question. I've edited it in for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over the map to compare keys. You just have to use the brace notation `[]` to get a map value by a dynamic key like so `${map[key]}`.

So, this should do:

```html
<c:forEach items="${addRatingExceptionForm.ratingsMap[addRatingExceptionForm.ratingElementDropdown]}" var="item"> 
  <li>
    <input type="checkbox" id="addRatingException_timeline_earlyAsn" value="${item.RatingInstanceValue}" class="ajaxContentTrigger method_Load_exceptionType ajaxLoadingTrigger|addRatingException_exceptionType clearErrors" />
    <label for="addRatingException_timeline_earlyAsn">${item.RatingInstanceValue}</p></label> <!-- wtf is that </p> doing there? -->
  </li>
</c:forEach>
```